# Add dynamically input in vuejs and display data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, push

I'm using vue2 and laravel 6, and i'm trying to add input field into my table where the `data:activities` had a relationship with `scores`

```
<button type="button"  @click="addAct" >add activity</button>
<tr v-for="(student,index) in students" :key="index">
  <td v-for="(quiz,i) in activities" :key="i">
     //When I used this i can display my data coming from DB. but i get an error
        <input  v-model="quiz.scores[index].scores"autocomplete="off" />
     //When i used this input i can add dynamically but i can't display my DB data
        <input  v-model="quiz.scores[index]" autocomplete="off" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

```
data() {
return {
    activities:[{"id":42,"activity_title":"1","hps":"1",
      "scores":[
          {"id":158,"scores":2,"student_id":1,"activity_id":42},
          {"id":159,"scores":2,"student_id":2,"activity_id":42},
          {"id":160,"scores":2,"student_id":3,"activity_id":42},
          {"id":161,"scores":2,"student_id":4,"activity_id":42}]
         }],
     students:[
          {"name":"Ellis Corkery MD","id":1},
          {"name":"Lucie Rau""id":2},
          {"name":"Delia Donnelly","id":3},
          {"name":"Chyna Barton","id":4}]
}
},
methods:{

   addAct: function() { 
       this.activities.push( { activity_title: [], hps:[], scores:[] );
       },
}
```

*[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: quiz.scores[_vm.index] is undefined".* I get this when i try using the first input into my template

Comment: I don't see the variables `index`, maybe you meant `i`?

Comment: Sorry. i forgot, but the `index` is props and i'm displaying a relationship into my input where the `scores:[]` have many values @ Robert Rocha

Comment: You should probably post all the code

Comment: I had edit my code @Robert Rocha

Comment: I still don't see where `quiz` is defined, you are linking quiz to a model?

Comment: isn't `quiz` only used for naming to access the data?

Comment: I believe whatever you have in `v-model` should point to what you have in your `data()` function/object

Comment: i tried to change my `quiz` to `scores` but i still get the same error. When i try using the second `input` i can add input continuously but i can't display my data which is `scores` in my `activities`

Comment: check your data format is correct ? is correct ? are you missing `]` if you verify correct data format then can help

Comment: everything in my format is correct. i only need to add `input`  when i clicked the `button` at the same time ineed to display my `scores` coming from my `activities` @ Hamelraj

Comment: you want only to fix  `is undefined` enough ?

Comment: yes. just add dynamically the input but i can also see the values of scores in my `input`

Answer (score 1):

In your Example you are pushing an object having scores an array with Zero length. and in you template you are looking for `quiz.scores[index].scores` thus the error it throws is correct

Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: quiz.scores[_vm.index] is undefined". I get this when i try using the first input into my template

v-model is looking for any variable which does not exist and so the error

Comment: Then how can i display my `scores` at the same time add an `input` field? @Prabhat Gupta

Comment: you should check whether you have such a property or not before you v-model with a v-if and do not render an input if such property does not exist like `v-if="quiz.scores[index]"`

Comment: thnaks. This did the work, but now i'm getting an error. `[Vue warn]: Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value.` . When i tried to edit or insert a value.

Comment: surly you will get the warning as per vue Implementation you need to define your all properties upfront that you are using in your template. however the properties you are assigning using push is dynamic and not reactive.

And to solve that you need to use `this.$set()` please folllow the bellow link to understand more.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 0):

Your **activities** data each item doesn't has `scores` so in you `activities` array first object has `scores` as per your data this should work

```
<tr v-for="(student,index) in students" :key="index">
  <td >
     //Now this should work
        <input  v-model="activities[0].scores[index]"autocomplete="off" />
     //as per data you have to check this 
        // <input  v-model="quiz.scores[index]" autocomplete="off" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: When i use this `<input  v-model="quiz.scores[index].scores" autocomplete="off" />` i can display my `scores`  in my `input`. It's almost the same with yours.  but how can i **add** another input field so i can insert another scores when i clicked the `button`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try change the `quiz` as `v-model` of `activity` like this :

```
<tr v-for="(student,index) in students" :key="index">
  <!-- Filter Student Scores -->
  <td>{{student.name}}</td>
  <td v-for="(iact, i) in activities" :key="i">
    <!-- Get Specific Student Score based on student_id -->
    <div v-for="(quiz, i2) in iact.scores" :key="i2">
      <input v-if="iact.scores[i2].student_id == student.id" v-model="iact.scores[i2].scores">
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In order to get `addAct` function work properly you should add initial value of the score like this :

```
this.activities.push({
    id: "",
    activity_title: "",
    hps: "",
    scores: [
      { id: 170, scores: null, student_id: 1, activity_id: 43 },
      { id: 170, scores: null, student_id: 2, activity_id: 43 },
      { id: 170, scores: null, student_id: 3, activity_id: 43 },
      { id: 170, scores: null, student_id: 4, activity_id: 43 }
    ]
  });
```

This is because you bind the v-model to the object of `activity[array].score[array].score`. Put empty value will lead to error.

My Previous answer :

Do you want to display each student activity score like this : ?

```
Name     | Activity 1 | Activity 2 |
---------+------------+-------------+
Student 1|    xxx     |    xxx     |
Student 2|    xxx     |    xxx     |
```

If yes, than may be you can try this :

```
<!-- Show Each Student Activity Scores :  n row  -->
<tr v-for="(student,index) in students" :key="index">
  <!-- For easier reading -->
  <td>{{student.name}}</td> 
  <!-- Loop each activity / quiz -->
  <td v-for="(quiz, i) in activities" :key="i">
    <!-- Get Specific Student Score based on student_id --> 
    <input v-if="quiz.scores[index].student_id == student.id" v-model="quiz.scores[index].scores">
  </td> 
</tr>
```

I have try it using codesandbox here : https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-activity-tlckd
Hope that help

Comment: thanks for some answers, but the `addAct` is only pushing to add new `input field` where i can insert some additional values to save into my DB. The `activities` holds my `data's` that's why i need 2 `input`. 1 is for displaying my values and 1 is for inserting.
 `<input v-if="scores.scores[index].index" v-model="scores.scores[index]" autocomplete="off" placeholder="first" /> ` 
`<input v-else v-model="scores.scores[index]" autocomplete="off" placeholder="second" />   `

Comment: I see... you are using quiz like as a dynamic variables. 
I suggest you use different approach here, because if you are using v-model=quiz then it should be bind to reactive properties quiz declared inside data. Maybe you can try put the  scores also in quiz ( array ) like activity.

Comment: Sorry. but i don't see any  progress to **codesandbox** .  I need the `button:add activity` to be initialize as empty when i clicked the button so i can insert a value. 
heres a sample [https://codesandbox.io/s/activities-qmrbv](https://codesandbox.io/s/activities-qmrbv)

Comment: so when i save the newly added data i can display them. but what i get is `[object object]` inside the input

Comment: Hey. Thanks. i already had an answer. i'll be posting it later. sorry fr the trouble.

Comment: Great. No trouble at all. ah, I just realize the updated one in codesandbox link has change. but nevermind. you found an anwers.